# Which results in probabilistic group theory generalize from finite groups to compact Hausdorff groups (and which don't)?

Tags: pr.probability, gr.group-theory, measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. It has been shown that:

1. If the probability that two randomly selected elements of $G$ generate an abelian group is greater than $5/8$, $G$ is abelian.
2. If the probability that two randomly selected elements of $G$ generate a solvable group is greater than $11/30$, $G$ is solvable.
3. If the probability that two randomly selected elements of $G$ generate a nilpotent group is greater than $1/2$, $G$ is nilpotent.
4. If the probability that two randomly selected elements of $G$ generate a group of odd order is greater than $11/30$, $G$ has odd order.

A proof of the first result, more often stated with "two randomly selected elements commute" in place of "generate an abelian group," can be found in [this blog post by John Baez](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/the-5-8-theorem/), who credits it to the paper "On some problems of a statistical group-theory, IV" by Erdős and Turán. The proofs of results 2-4 can be found in the paper [The Probability of Generating a Finite Soluble Group](https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/81/2/405/1571778) by Guralnick and Wilson.

The proof of result 1 generalizes quite readily to the case where $G$ is a compact Hausdorff topological group  (equipped with a Haar measure $\mu$). The details of such a proof can be found in the question [Applications of the 5/8 Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224017/applications-of-the-5-8-theorem) by diracdeltafunk. In my view, this is due to the fact that the two main bounds used in the proof (that $[G \colon Z(G)] \geq 4$ for all nonabelian groups $G$ and $[G \colon C_{G}(g)] \geq 2$ for all noncentral elements $g \in G$) hold for all groups, and not just finite ones.

On the other hand, the proofs of results 2-4 do not seem to admit an easy generalization to the case of compact Hausdorff $G$: many propositions use the finiteness of $G$, and some of the related main results even use the Classification of Finite Simple Groups.

In view of these differences, my question is:

**What are some other results in probabilistic group theory which are stated for finite groups, but have a proof that can easily be generalized to the case of compact Hausdorff groups, and what are some results with obvious obstacles to doing so?**

Comment: What would even be the analogue of 4 for infinite groups?

Comment: @Wojowu Since the conditions "having only elements of odd order" and "having odd order" are equivalent for finite groups, I'm thinking it might be something like: "If the probability that two elements of a compact Hausdorff group $G$ generate a subgroup of odd order is $11/30,$ then every element of $G$ has odd order."

Comment: Maybe you should ask first: Are there counterexamples to 2 and 3 for compact Hausdorff groups?

Comment: I’m not sure that the analogue of 4 is interesting — is there a compact Hausdorff group where the elements of finite order have positive measure?

Comment: @MattF. Good idea, I will ask for counterexamples in a separate question if no answers are provided here. To address your concern about the analogue of 4: if we take a finite, discrete group $G$, and consider the product of infinitely many copies of $G$, don't we get an (infinite) compact Hausdorff group where every element has finite order?

Comment: @ckefa, yes, that is a good example for #4, and you could include it in the question.

Comment: Putting 4 aside, I would guess 'yes' is the answer to 1,2,3 because in a compact Lie group that does not satisfy a law, two random elements generate a free group with probability 1. So that looks promising for reducing to the profinite case. Well there are a few details to fill in .. so I am not claiming to have the answer. 4 is different for reasons explained in the comments above.